# change datatype in stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

In my project I have 1000 stored procedure and all of them have some `numeric(18,2)` parameter and our client's requirement have changed to up to 4 digits after the decimal point. So I have to change all stored procedure's parameter's datatype to `numeric(18,4)`.

So now how I can modify the datatype for many stored procedures? Please give me an solution if any code exist for that then give the code in `vb.net`....

Thanks in advance....

Comment: if this project is inside Visual Studio, have you considered ctrl+h?

Comment: yes,for that i have to open every sp and i dont want to do using ctrl+h...@3dd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the script for only stored procedure. Select Stored procedure only from Script Wizard.
[image]

Then apply the changes for `numeric(18,2)` to `numeric(18,4)` in your script.Even you can find and replace the string. but, make sure there is a risk to replace specific parameter type. After doing all changes you can run that script in SSMS Query Window.

**NOTE:** When you are doing change in `precision` of parameters. then you have to also change  the `precision` of declared datatype in stored procedure.